# Does Spring data redis support pop multiple elements for set operations?

Tags: spring, spring-data-redis

As the title, i found jedis support pop multiple elements [jedis commands source code](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/commands/JedisCommands.java#L127)

I reviewed spring-data-redis project's source code, and cant't find any method support this.

How could i do for pop multiple elements in spring data redis?

Comment: Please share what you attempted/tried to help us better understand your question.

Comment: i need a method for pop random member in redis set,the method signature like blew：
public Collection<String> pop(String key,long count);

Comment: spring data redis currently do not support this method，it only provide one method that can pop only one random element in redis set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RedisSetCommands#spop(key, count)` and its counterpart in `SetOperations` is currently not implemented in Spring Data Redis. I've opened [DATAREDIS-668](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-668) to add support for the `count` option.

Meanwhile you can use `RedisTemplate#execute` to obtain the value via the underlying connection, having the template take care of resource handling.

```java
redisTemplate.execute((RedisCallback<Set<String>>) conn -> {

  Jedis jedis = (Jedis) conn.getNativeConnection(); // access native driver 
  return jedis.spop(key, count);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SetOperations#pop](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/SetOperations.html#pop-K-) to pop a random element. Just define a `RedisTemplate`

```
<bean id="jedisConnFactory"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
      p:use-pool="true"/>

<bean id="redisTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
      p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnFactory"/>
```

And then you can inject it as `SetOperations`

```
@Resource(name="redisTemplate")
private SetOperations<String, String> operation;
```

You can find other `RedisTemplate` views at [Working with Objects through RedisTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.8.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis:template)

You can also use JDK collection interfaces, see [Support Classes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:support)

Comment: Thanks your reply.
All elements store in redis set. and i want use spop command for random element pop.
I reviewed redis LPOP command in redis.io, the command do not fix my problem.

Comment: @ChenglongXu you can use [SetOperations#pop](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/SetOperations.html#pop-K-) for random element pop. Just inject `SetOperations` instead of `ListOperations`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks your reply.I know this, i wan pop more than one element in one time,redis's spop command accept an optional parameter ‘count’, this can specify how much elements will pop.
Jedis library have api can do this, but spring data redis do not encapsulate this api.